# Div not overflowing properly afer inner html is changed programmaticaly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a website where you can search for music from a searchbar and I want suggestions to appear while the user is typing, so I use javascript to programmaticaly fill a div containing the results, but it overflows out of the window without either making the body or the div itself scrollable, even though it's set to auto...

As you can see further the child div is about 2000px high which is way more than the parent div. I read that if the root element is set to 100% it's ok to use % heights, and it seems to because it works for the parent (if I take it off the parent will also be 2000px). What I don't get is why doesn't it work for the child div?

I took off some elements for readability but if the mistake isn't here I can add them.

## CSS

```
html, 
body {
    background-color: #2288ff;
    background-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(10% 20%, rgb(50,150,255), rgb(10,70,255));
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content_box {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#searchbox{
    border: 3px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 30px;
}

#results {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-color: #000000;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="content_box">
    <div id="searchbox">
        <form oninput="obtain()" action="/library/mresult.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onclick="shrink()">
            <input id="SInput" type="text" name="searchstring" onblur="expand()"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="results" >
    </div>
</div>
```

## Screenshots

[image: The parent div is window height]

[image: The child div overflows even though it's set to auto]

Comment: Have you try body{ overflow-x: hidden }

Comment: I just did, it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide a working demo with the help of jsfiddle? So that people can help you better

Comment: @Hadron I am although not able to recreate your problem. You can limit `overflow: auto` to just one direction using `overflow-y: auto` or `overflow-x: auto`, if that helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a div scrollable inside another `overflow: hidden` container you need to define a `height` for its parent. So for example you could wrap your `#results` in another div:

```
#wrapper {
  height: 200px;
}
#results { 
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; /* just vertical scrolling if needed */
}
```

and some basic html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="results">
   <!-- your content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise the #results div will expand as much as needed, so that there is no need for scrolling, while the user is not able to see anything outside the viewport, because scrolling is forbidden.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dsyy69o8/1/)